# example grid system using flexbox.

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to achieve this using flexbox :
[image]

1. textarea should remain fixed with cols="15".
2. use only 1 flexbox container or very minimum possible.
3. least extra div's possible.

```css
/*Basic Grid Styles*/
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width:600px;
  height: 300px;
}
.grid-cell{
 height:300px;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="grid">
<textarea rows="20" cols="15" name="" class="grid-cell"></textarea>
<div class="grid-cell">
<input type="submit" value="10 >>> 13" name="submit_a" class=""/>
<input type="submit" value="10 <<< 13" name="submit_b" class=""/>
</div>
<textarea rows="20" cols="15" name="" class="grid-cell"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properly, aligned and buttons positioned the way you want.

```css
/*Basic Grid Styles*/
.grid {
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center; /* IE */
  -webkit-align-items: center; /* Chrome / Safari */
  -webkit-box-align: center; /* Chrome / Safari */
  align-items: center; /* standard */
  justify-content: center;
  width:600px;
  height: 300px;
}

.grid-cell {
margin : 5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="grid">
    <textarea rows="20" cols="15" name="" class="grid-cell"></textarea>
    <div class="grid-cell">
      <input type="submit" value="10 >>> 13" name="submit_a" class=""/><br/><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="10 <<< 13" name="submit_b" class=""/>
    </div>
    <textarea rows="20" cols="15" name="" class="grid-cell"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `align-items` with the vendor prefixes to fallback, and remove the height on the middle container (to achieve the perfect and automatic vertical centering)

```css
/*Basic Grid Styles*/
.grid {
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center; /* IE */
  -webkit-align-items: center; /* Chrome / Safari */
  -webkit-box-align: center; /* Chrome / Safari */
  align-items: center; /* standard */
  justify-content: center;
  width:600px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="grid">
    <textarea rows="20" cols="15" name="" class="grid-cell"></textarea>
    <div class="grid-cell">
      <input type="submit" value="10 >>> 13" name="submit_a" class=""/>
      <input type="submit" value="10 <<< 13" name="submit_b" class=""/>
    </div>
    <textarea rows="20" cols="15" name="" class="grid-cell"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: as per requirement in image it in vertically one below the other but you have display inline ??

Comment: @IqbalPasha I don't understand what you say.